# Different values of mae using model.evaluate and mean_absolue_error

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

Given a tensor dataset valid_ds:

```
<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((None, 10, 224, 224, 3), (None, 5)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>
```

I evaluate the model like this:

```
loss, mae = model.evaluate(valid_ds)
```

I got a mae: 0.9125

But if I extract `y_true` from `valid_ds` by doing:

```
y_true = np.concatenate([y for x,y in valid_ds], axis=0)
```

Then I calculate the mae using `mean_absolute_error` from `sklearn.metrics`

```
y_pred = model.predict(valid_ds)

mae = mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)
```

I got a mae equals to: 0.8532

Can someone tell me why I get different values of mae?

I expect to have the same values of mae by different ways